# How to hide or encrypt a query string variable

Tags: javascript, php

How can i make the variable 'success' that is passed to 'payment_success.php' below to be somehow encrypted, i don't want the user to know the exact variable name passed. i wanted using post method, but i can't use it for my call back function. Any idea will be a great help

```
 callback: function(response){
           const referenced = response.reference;
           window.location.href='payment_success.php?success='+referenced;
      },
```

Comment: You can't hide it. Only obfuscate. If you want it hidden, keep it on the server-side.

Comment: Do you have access to the page that is generating the reference code on the server side? If so, you can just use a session or database with the session to store it and redirect the visitor and they will never know the variable exists.

Comment: Why does the variable name matter, isn't the value more sensitive?

Comment: how can i use the php session to store the javascript referenced const, can i use php session in a script tag to store a const, like my code here.//                                                                         
  const referenced = response.reference;                                             $_SESSION['success''] = referenced;

Answer (score 0):

The following is one of tricks I used in a project trying to hide a piece of data.

Assuming your string variable is "123abc".

You may first add a random suffix of three characters , so the string can be:

AC1 C8D E9u Z77 Vux

After that you may use a further trick to put your code "123abc" into a format like the following

1[3 random characters]2[4 random characters]3a[2 random characters]bc[3 random characters]

So the result of 123abc will be like

XXX1XXX2XXXX3aXXbcXXX

so can be any one of the following:

56f134a2rxxq3a43bcccd

97z1zux289873a5tbczwq

Eu11qzv2739u3auubc76x

and so on....

After passing to your PHP script, please extract the correct data.

If you want to be safer, split the characters more further apart by inserting longer random characters in between.

You may use further imagination to do the trick. For example, generate a string which can be random in length of the "mixing codes".

Comment: Thank you for your help